# Hadoop getting time difference between dates

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I am struggling something like this in hadoop

I get following as a result of my mapper

```
KeyValue1, 2014-02-01 20:42:00
KeyValue1, 2014-02-01 20:45:12
KeyValue1, 2014-05-01 10:35:02
KeyValue2, 2014-03-01 01:45:12
KeyValue2, 2014-03-01 02:08:18
KeyValue3, 2014-02-01 20:45:12
KeyValue4, 2015-02-01 05:45:12
KeyValue4, 2013-02-01 10:45:12
```

and goes on..

At the end of the day I want this;

```
 KeyValue1, TimeDifference(first occurrence - last occurrence)
 KeyValue2, TimeDifference(first occurrence - last occurrence)
 KeyValue3, -occured once-
 KeyValue4, TimeDifference(first occurrence - last occurrence)
```

Any input is highly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Emit the same order to a reducer. In the reducer, for each unique key, iterate the list of values. Set 2 variables for first and last dates and update them as and when you get a bigger or smaller date. At the end of iteration, get the difference and emit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches. I will suggest use a composite key. Create custom Partitioner, KeyComparator and GroupComparator. Then on reducer side you can simple pick 1st and last row and take a difference.